# PHP Table Not Created

Tags: php, html, joomla, html-table, joomla3.0

I am using php to query a sql server database and write the results onscreen.  I thought all my echo statements with table & tr/td were creating a table to display the results in, however when the data is shown on screen it appears run together like the below:

```
Employee EmployeeIDPrice1Price2Price3Price4Price5
```

etc with no table structure.  What should I change in this syntax so that an actual table is created to display results in?

```
if ($result = mssql_execute($proc)) 
{
    $number_of_rows = mssql_num_rows($result);
    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >Employee </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">EmployeeID </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price1 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price2 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price3 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price4 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price5 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price6 </th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price7</th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price8</th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price9</th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price10</th>';
        echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price11</th>';
        echo '</tr>';  

    while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$Row['Employee'] . 
        '</td><td>'.$Row['EmployeeID'] . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price1']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price2']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price3']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price4']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price5']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price6']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price7']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price8']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price9']) .
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price10']) . 
        '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price11']) . 
        '</td></tr>';
    }
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

**EDIT**
This is what my output looks like, even after adding in a cellpadding="5"  ... not a clearly defined table like i expected when using the html words `table` and `td` `tr`  -- meaning all the data just bleeds together, instead of having a table set-up like I thought I defined.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score -1):

This is not the right structure
Must be like this:

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Even thought I am returning results from sql server I do not force to use echo statements?

Comment: If I do not use echo statements I get a 500 Error when I try to access the page.

Answer (score -1):

`echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" style="width: 100%;">';`

Increase cellpadding as required.

But I recommend you read up on css as a future improvement.

<del>Also, this line has a syntax error: `'</td><td>."$".round($Row['Price6']) .`</del>

<del>It should be: `'</td><td>'."$".round($Row['Price6']) .`</del> - you fixed this since I posted!

Or even better: `'</td><td>$'.round($Row['Price6']) .`

Comment: Just to clarify, cellpadding="1" will give you one pixel of space around your cells. cellpadding="5" would give you 5 pixels etc. Is this answer helpful or are you still not seeing it display how you want?

Comment: Still not the output I am after.  It is all just run together, like words in a book.  I am after a clean ordered table like the w3schools link provided below.

Comment: Even with cellpadding="5" ? Could you give the actual html output you get?

Comment: Yes - even adding in cellpadding="5" it adds space between the values, similar to space between words in a book.  But does not set-up the table structure.

Comment: Also, you could try a combination of the two answers. echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">';

Comment: I added image to show what my output looks like, just all run together.

Comment: Looking at your latest edit to the question, that looks like you are outputting several tables, I would be interested to see what the html output is.

Comment: I am outputting 1 table, but multiple rows.  It is the result of a SQL Server stored procedure.  Returns anywhere between 1 and 20 rows.

Comment: Can you please show the html output? paste it into http://pastebin.com/ and link to it here

Comment: Like the screenshot I provided?

Comment: I would need to see the actual html code that caused that rendering. e.g. view source in the browser and paste it.

Comment: That is what is provided in my OP

Comment: You have given a snippet that looks like it might contain span tags and therefore isn't related to the php code you have also provided. The image you have provided is helpful, and now I just need the pure html code that's generated by the php. What would be helpful is to give the html code that appears in the browser as a pastebin link.